# Detecting string in MySQL database, prepend if false?

Tags: mysql, sql, prepend

Couldn't find anything useful elsewhere so posting here...

I have a MySQL table setup, in this table is the column 'socialurl'

Some values in 'socialurl' are formatted like this: http://www.facebook.com/mypage

Where as other values are formatted like this: mypage

What I would like to do is detect whether 'http://www.facebook.com/' is included in 'socialurl' - if it is not detected then I would like to prepend 'http://www.facebook.com/' to the value stored.

So all values will end up being 'http://www.facebook.com/mypage'

Thanks

Comment: You can achieve this using triggers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
  mytable 
SET 
  socialurl = CONCAT('http://www.facebook.com', socialurl) 
WHERE 
  socialurl NOT LIKE 'http://www.facebook.com/%'
```

Comment: Well to every value that is not like the specified condition. If you have other values in this column you'll have to adapt the where-part to exclude them.